# pythonanywhere - how to configure pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py

Tags: wsgi, pythonanywhere

I have a simple application written in plain python made by 4 files:

```
menu.py
db1.py
db2.py
db3.py
```

located in `/home/???/site`

but I've not understood how to configure

```
https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/???/files/var/www/???_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py
```

that is currently set to

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    if environ.get('PATH_INFO') == '/':
        status = '200 OK'
        content = MAIN_MENU
    else:
        status = '404 NOT FOUND'
        content = 'Page not found.'
    response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html'), ('Content-Length', str(len(content)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    yield content.encode('utf8')
```

to make it work correctly:

it is suggested to

```
# +++++++++++ CUSTOM WSGI +++++++++++
# If you have a WSGI file that you want to serve using PythonAnywhere, perhaps
# in your home directory under version control, then use something like this:
#
#import sys
#
#path = '/home/jslab/path/to/my/app
#if path not in sys.path:
#    sys.path.append(path)
#
#from my_wsgi_file import application  # noqa
```

but I have `no version control` and neither a `my_wsgi_file.py`

clearly with current settings, if I type

```
???.pythonanywhere.com/menu.py
```

into the browser, I get `Page not found`

can pls suggest how to set it up?

Thanks

Comment: You do not execute python file in the browser. What is in menu.py? WSGI application has to provide a callable application object.

Comment: in menu.py there is basically only html
actually there are 3 print command that draw 3 anchor tags to db1.py, db2.py, db3.py

Comment: It sounds like you need to follow a basic website development tutorial -- perhaps the one at https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121 would be a good start?